# My search feature isn't showing posts without a tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I've implemented a search feature in to my rails project, alongside the ActsAsTaggableOn gem so I can tag my Post model, however when I use my search function it doesn't show posts with no tags, below is my code:

Search Controller

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
    def search
      if params[:q].nil?
        @posts = []
      else
        @posts = Post.search params[:q]
      end
    end
end
```

Post Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_taggable

    def self.search(search)
      joins(:tags)
      .where("title LIKE :search OR content LIKE :search OR tags.name LIKE :search", search: "%#{search}%")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code produces query with an `INNER JOIN`, but you need a `LEFT JOIN`, so query with:

```
includes(:tags).references(:tags).where( # the remaining of your query
```

or write a join statement yourself:

```
joins("LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id=...") # incomplete
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, managed to crack this using the left join - joins("LEFT JOIN tags ON posts.id=tags.id")

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using joins in your search query. As a result of that it generates an **inner join** these joins expect related data to exist on both tables. So, if you don't have any tags it won't be returned by this code. If you want both tagged and untagged data then, you could rather use an includes statement as follows.

```
def self.search(search)
  includes(:tags)
  .where("title LIKE :search OR content LIKE :search OR tags.name LIKE :search", search: "%#{search}%")
end
```